# while python read from file

Tags: python, file, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
variables = [0, 0, 0, 0]

while (variables[2]<4):
    with open('vystup_online.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            variables = (line.strip().split())
    print variables[2]
```

and here's my .txt file:

```
2 10.249402 0.000000 25.596176
```

I was assuming it will print variables[2] until I change the file to:

```
2 10.249402 1.000000 25.596176
```

or similar.

I am just getting

```
>>>
0.000000
```

and nothing more. What's wrong?

This is what I need:

```
>>>
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
...
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to watch a file for changes? This sounds somewhat like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variables[2]<4` will always be False at the second iteration.

since `variables[2]` is a string after the line `variables = (line.strip().split())` and `4` is an `int`

and in python 2.x `while string < int` will result as `False`

you can read more about your mistake [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270680/1982962)

Comment: sure...didn't notice that. It should look like this: `while (float(variables[2])<4):` now it works.

Answer (score 1):

`variables[2]` is a string. `'0.000000' < 4` is false.